# code to mesh the area of overlapping

Tags: c++

I'm using clipper library to determine the area of overlapping of two polygons in C++. After finding the overlapping area, I'm meshing it, or overlap it again with a grid that has a uniform step size (in this case, 0.06). Here is my code:

```
#include "cohesive.h"
#include "clipper.h"

int main() {

    using namespace ClipperLib;

    //Clipper library used to get the overlapping vertices
    Paths subj(1), clip(1), solution, clip1(1), mesh;
    //define 'subject' polygon
    subj[0] << 
    IntPoint(0*1e5,3*1e5) << IntPoint(3*1e5,4*1e5) <<
    IntPoint(3*1e5,-1*1e5) << IntPoint(0*1e5,0*1e5);

    //define 'clipping' polygon
    clip[0] << 
    IntPoint(-2*1e5,2*1e5) << IntPoint(2*1e5,2*1e5) <<
    IntPoint(2*1e5,-2*1e5) << IntPoint(-2*1e5,-2*1e5);

    //perform intersection ...
    Clipper c;
    c.AddPaths(subj, ptSubject, true);
    c.AddPaths(clip, ptClip, true);
    c.Execute(ctIntersection, solution, pftNonZero, pftNonZero);

    //size or number of vertices for the overlapping area
    int size = 0.0;
    vector<double> Xp;
    vector<double> Yp;
    if (solution.size() > 0) 
    {
    size = solution[0].size();
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
    Xp.push_back(solution[0][k].X/1e5);
    Yp.push_back(solution[0][k].Y/1e5);
                                    }
    }

    //the overlapping area ---- Function to get the area of a polygon
    double A_lap = polygonArea(Xp, Yp, size);

    //Sort the Xs and Ys
    sort(Xp.begin(),Xp.end());
    sort(Yp.begin(),Yp.end());

    //The range of the mesh
    double xrange = Xp[size-1] - Xp[0];
    double yrange = Yp[size-1] - Yp[0];

    cout << "x range is  " << xrange << endl;
    cout << "y range is  " << yrange << endl;

    //Step to be used in the mesh (both X and Y)
    //Here the step is 30% of the particle size
    //The maximum soil particle size is 0.2
    double step = 0.3*0.2;
    int no = ((xrange >= yrange)?xrange:yrange)/step;

    //vectors xs and ys are the coordinates of the grid to be used in meshing
    vector<double> xs, ys;
    for (int k1 = 0 ; k1 < no+2 ; k1++) {

        xs.push_back(Xp[0]+k1*step);
        ys.push_back(Yp[0]+k1*step);
                                        }
    for (int i = 0; i < no+1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < no+1; j++){
            double A_lap1 = 0.0;
            int size1 = 0;
            clip1[0] << IntPoint(xs[i]*1e5,ys[j]*1e5) << IntPoint(xs[i]*1e5,ys[j+1]*1e5) <<
            IntPoint(xs[i+1]*1e5,ys[j+1]*1e5) << IntPoint(xs[i+1]*1e5,ys[j]*1e5);

            Clipper c1;
            c1.AddPaths(solution, ptSubject, true);
            c1.AddPaths(clip1, ptClip, true);
            c1.Execute(ctIntersection, mesh, pftNonZero, pftNonZero);
            vector<double> Xp1;
            vector<double> Yp1;
            if (mesh.size() > 0) {
              size1 = mesh[0].size();
               for (int k2 = 0; k2 < size1; k2++) {
               Xp1.push_back(mesh[0][k2].X/1e5);
               Yp1.push_back(mesh[0][k2].Y/1e5);
                                                  }

            //the overlapping area
            A_lap1 = polygonArea(Xp1, Yp1, size1);
            vector<double> Areas;
            Areas.push_back(A_lap1);
                                 }
            clip1.clear(); Xp1.clear(); Yp1.clear(); A_lap1 = 0.0; mesh.clear();
                                     }
                                 }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm interested in getting a vector that has the overlapping of the big area with the grids. The code generates an error of (vector subscript is out of range) using microsoft visual studio 2010. Can you please help in this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys! I got it!!

The code for meshing works very well. You just need to add: 
Paths clip1(1), mesh;

after: 
for (int j = 0; j < no + 1; j++) {